# ionic image upload to cloudinary

Tags: ionic-framework, cloudinary

Please tell where to specify the upload_preset and also help with the image uploading part.

```
let options : FileUploadOptions = {
  params:{'upload_preset':'preset1'},

  }
const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
fileTransfer.upload('assets/demo.jpg', 
'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/dvkvdp0bp/image/upload', options,true)
.then((data) => {
  alert('DONE!');
}, (err) => {
  // error
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a video to show how to add an upload preset:
http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/video/upload/v1521058712/upload-preset_j96a2f.mp4

If you want, you're more than welcomed to [open a ticket](http://support.cloudinary.com/tickets/new) and we'll be happy to suggest specific tips for you regarding uploading an image.

Comment: I have already done what the video demonstrated. I would like to know where should I mention upload_preset in the code above in order to upload image in cloudinary using file transfer plugin. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, upload preset is wrapped in '', please remove that.
The following worked for me.

```
let options = {
      params: {
        upload_preset : 'example',
        api_key:'187673838930038',
        file:filename,
      } 
    }
```